# Zend based modules

Tags: zend-framework

Anybody knows about the URL. Where I can get already build modules in zend framework as we get plugins in joomla so that I can use them directly. For an example banner management module, notification and otheres.

Is there any place where I can get this??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

Zend Framework is a development framework, NOT a Content Management Framework like Drupal or Joomla.

All information regarding the Zend Framework can be found at http://framework.zend.com.

Other useful resources are :

- [ZendCasts](http://www.zendcasts.com/)
- [Zend Framework Webinars](http://www.zend.com/resources/webinars/framework)
- [Surviving The Deep End](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/)
- [ZF Snippets](http://www.zfsnippets.com/)
- [ZF Forums](http://www.zfforums.com/)

For a Zend Framework based CMS : you could checkout [Digitalus](http://www.digitaluscms.com) or [TomatoCMS](http://www.tomatocms.com)

Comment: I know that. I just want to confirm that we have any community or place where we can have such types of modules or not.

Anyways Thanks for reply

Comment: Ok, it wasn't exactly clear from your question that you knew that already. Modified my answer a bit to give some extra pointers.