# Zend Framework plugins?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there somewhere a repository/list of third party ZF plugins?

I mean plugins like this one: http://code.google.com/p/zfdebug/

Thank you. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zend based modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195428/zend-based-modules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Home . It's a listing of proposals to be actually included in ZF. Not all of them have code.

Comment: Technically, these are not plugins though. And they are not 3rd party either.

Comment: Good point. My understanding was plugins = components. The question is then for plugins for the main MVC components of ZF (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.plugins.intro.html) which have a plugin architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Try http://www.zfsnippets.com/

I am not aware of any repository where you can download ready-made modules. You might be interested in the learning resources given at [Zend based modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195428/zend-based-modules) though.